# Bluetooth on Android: startDiscovery doesn't work and I have bluetooth enabled

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am having troubles using startDiscovery(). Here is the problem, I have registered the following Intents to my BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
IntentFilter filterFound = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
IntentFilter filterStart = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
IntentFilter filterStop = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filterFound);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filterStart);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filterStop);
```

Here is my broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive (myReceiver)");
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // When discovery finds a device
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
        Log.d(TAG,device.getName() + " " + device.getAddress());
        deviceListAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
    if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Started discovery");
    }
    if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Finished discovery");
    }
}
};
```

When I call startDiscovery on my bluetooth adapter (bluetooth existing and enabled), nothing happens and I can't see anything in the logcat regarding the BroadcastReceiver.

Did you already experience that kind of problem? Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the appropriate permissions on your [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/gtosoft/libvoyager/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml). In particular, to perform a discovery you need  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Brad Hein make sure AndroidManifest has bluetooth permission.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

For registering bluetooth scan result broadcast receiver follow the below method.

```
IntentFilter bluetoothFilter = new IntentFilter();
bluetoothFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
bluetoothFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
bluetoothFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

registerReceiver(myReceiver, bluetoothFilter);
```

**Start bluetooth discovery as follows.**

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
   // No bluetooth Hardware found.
}
if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    // Bluetooth is OFF
}

if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
    // cancel the discovery if it has already started
   bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
}

if (bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()) {
    // bluetooth has started discovery
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the receiver as follows :

```
private class SingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction(); 

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED)) {
            log(getTimeStamp() + ":discovery started");
        }
```

And here is the order needed in the function calls :

1- cancelDiscovery() + getAdapter()

2- start the receiver as follows :

```
        mReceiver = new SingBroadcastReceiver();

        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        ifilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        ifilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter);
```

3- startDiscovery()